# How to show convergence in probability

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent identically distributed random variables. And $h_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n1_E(X_n)$ for an event $E$. Now i want to show, that for $0\leq p < \frac{1}{2}$:

$n^p(h_n(E)-P(X_1 \in E)) \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I suspect that $n$ might be missing. Shouldn't it be $h_n={\color{red}{n^{-1}}}\sum_{k=1}^n1_E(X_k)$?..

Comment: Of course thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the weak law of large numbers,
$$
h_n(E)-P(X_1\in E)\to 0
$$
in probability as $n\to\infty$. By the central limit theorem,
$$
\sqrt n(h_n(E)-P(X_1\in E))
$$
converges in distribution to a normal random variable as $n\to\infty$. Hence, we have that
$$
n^p(h_n(E)-P(X_1\in E))=n^{p-1/2}\sqrt n(h_n(E)-P(X_1\in E))\to0
$$
in probability as $n\to\infty$.